# external HDD Start Boot Laptop

Tags: boot, hard-drive, startup, external-hdd

I just change the internal hdd for a new one. It worked perfect, I just wanted an SSD
I forgot to copy some passwords I had in the old one. Both HDD has Ubuntu install
Can I start my computer using the old hdd like external ? I really don't want to change hdds again
Thank you

Comment: Yes you can do what you want, if your hardware (specifically the firmware) allows for it. One some devices I've found it easy, on others not so. It'll depend on your firmware (ie. machine specific) and settings made in uEFI/BIOS setup (at least in my experience).

Comment: Agree with above.  The old insrtall probably reference sda.  When your computer boots is might make the esternal sdb or something else.  Then grub on that hard drive does not know where to look. Replacing them physically is best.  BUT if its just passwords or stuff stored in text files and the like then just boot the new one.  Plug in the old one.  Browse and copy.

Comment: I busted up an old external 2.5" drive that did not work. I extracted the bit that attached to the cable and drive. Now I plug that into old 2.5" drives when I want to boot them externally.